# Why does $ (A^T x) · y = x · (A y) $ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why does $ (A^T x)· y = x ·(A y) $ hold?

The proof has to do with properties of transposes. I did a proof using coordinates (which was correct) but there is an infinitely easier way to do it.

A is an n by n matrix.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are column vectors, then $x$ and $Ay$ are column vectors, so what does $x(Ay)$ mean?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Assuming the inner product is $u\cdot v=u^Tv$, just expand out $(A^Tx)^Ty$ and $x^T(Ay)$ and compare.

Comment: This looks good but why does u⋅v=u^Tv? What property is this?

Comment: @orbis The usual dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=\sum_{i=1}^nu_iv_i$, which is precisely the result of $\mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{v}$ (I assume you know how to multiply two matrices).

Comment: I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @RahulNarain Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment:

It doesn't...and I think there is some inner product and there're some assumptions on $\,A\,$, since if we denote by $\,\langle\,x,y\,\rangle\,$ the inner product of $\,x,y\,$ , then

$$\langle\,Ax\,,\,y\,\rangle=\langle\,x\,,\,A^*y\,\rangle$$

where $\,A^*\,$ is the [adjoint](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEkQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.colostate.edu%2F~hulpke%2Flectures%2Fm369%2Fadjoint.pdf&ei=9ZdCUeiCMoSYhQfC5ICgAg&usg=AFQjCNGMri44gJxfVBPmYyKkmEw7dXQcIA&sig2=eAFLxewn3kyvg4JeQaxJhg) of $\,A\,$ so *if* this is what is meant in your link and *if* $\, A^*=A^t\,$ then we're done (for example, if the linear space is real and we're working with an orthonormal basis...)

Comment: The dot product should be between y and (ATx) on the left side. On the right it should be between x and (Ay). A is an n x n matrix (I'll edit to include this). x,y exists for all Rn.

Comment: It doesn't matter, @orbis, since $\,(A^t)^t=A\,$ ...